# Why is C# converting an implicitly typed variable to a nullable type?

Tags: c#, .net-5, nullable-reference-types

I have this code, written in a .NET 5 C# project with the nullable feature enabled:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, $"*.{extension}", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

when I suddenly notice that the `Directory.GetFiles` method returns type `string[]`, but somehow the variable `files` is of type `string[]?`.

Why is this? Does `var` automatically convert all variables to nullable types? That seems... really annoying!

If I change the declaration to `string[]` instead of `var`, then the variable is typed correctly, but I still get this weird "files is not null here" in the tooltip later on when I reference the variable, even though it can't ever be null because it's a non-nullable type...

```
foreach (var file in files) // hover over this files variable to see the "not null here" tooltip
{
    // about to add some code here
}
```